# QT Quick Control 2 Combobox cannot select Text

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

This code blocks work fine with import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
    import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

    Rectangle {

        property bool isval: true
        objectName: "havadurumuCombo"
        anchors.fill: parent

        ComboBox {
            id:havadurumuCombo
            model:combohava.datalist
            textRole: "value"
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height


    }
```

I have changed QtQuick.Controls 1.4 to import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 . I have experienced strance behavior. I choose combobox then drop down with information in model.That is OK. But I cannot choose any text on combobox.If ı select with curson on dropdown menu, then There is no text appears on it after closing dropdown.

Comment: Attach a minimal standalone example that reproduces the problem. We cannot run your code if it has references to something like `combohava.datalist` which is not included in the snippet.

Comment: Does the combo box in the gallery example work as expected?